# How do I solve Mailboxer reply undefined method `is_trashed?' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mailboxer

I'm trying to get Mailboxer gem working in a Rails 3.1 app... I have the New message function working, but replying to a conversation keeps giving me an `undefined method 'is_trashed?' for nil:NilClass` error.

I've been following the read me info on the gem site, [here](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer), and looking at the example mailboxer app [here](https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app).

Here's my controller:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  helper_method :mailbox, :conversation

  def show
    @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    recipient_emails = conversation_params(:recipients).split(',')
    recipients = User.where(email: recipient_emails).all

    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, *conversation_params(:body, :subject)).conversation

    redirect_to conversation
  end

  def reply
    conversation = current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body)).conversation
    redirect_to conversation
  end

  def trash
    conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def untrash
    conversation.untrash(current_user)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def mailbox
    @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
  end

  def conversation
    @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
  end

  def conversation_params(*keys)
    fetch_params(:conversation, *keys)
  end

  def message_params(*keys)
    fetch_params(:message, *keys)
  end

  def fetch_params(key, *subkeys)
    params[key].instance_eval do
      case subkeys.size
      when 0 then self
      when 1 then self[subkeys.first]
      else subkeys.map{|k| self[k] }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my reply form:

```
<%= simple_form_for :message, url: [:reply, conversation] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body, as: :text, :input_html => { :cols => 50, :rows => 3 } %>
  <div >
    <%= f.button :submit, "Send", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

New conversations are working, but for some reason I keep getting errors on the `reply_to_conversation` functionality. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the server just needed to be restarted... Not sure why, because this was only on the controller and view side of things. It's working now!